# Get background-img url and use it to create a new <img> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of hyperlink that uses background-image. And want to pop out a modal window with a image of the same source as the background. But can't seem to get it to work.

My js code currently

```
$('a.portfolio-item').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = $('.modal-body');
    content.empty();
    var img = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/^url\(|\)$/g, "");
    content.html('<img src="'+ img +'">');   <---- need help here 
    $(".modal-profile").modal({show:true});
});
```

html

```
<a class="portfolio-item" style="background-image: url(img/portfolio-1.jpg);">
   <div class="details">
      <h4>Portfolio 1</h4>
      <span>description here</span>
   </div>
</a>

<!-- .modal-profile -->
<div class="modal fade modal-profile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalProfile" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- //.modal-profile -->
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample HTML+CSS for `a.portfolio-item` so that we could see what source content you're working with.

Comment: edited to include HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change as below remove `"` from src please find below snippet for your reference

```
content.html('<img src='+ img +'>');
```

```js
$('a.portfolio-item').click(function(event){
debugger;
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = $('.modal-body');
    content.empty();
    var img = $(this).parent().css('background-image').replace(/^url\(|\)$/g, "");
    content.html('<img src='+ img +'>');  
    $(".modal-profile").modal();
});
```

```css
.block a{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:25px; // spared height: from the top;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-99999px;
    
    left:0;
    bottom:0; // or you can try with top:175px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="position:relative; background: url('https://dummyimage.com/200x200') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; background-position: bottom;" class="block block2 ">
   <ul class="elem"></ul>
   <span class="left_border"></span>
   <a href='#' class="portfolio-item">link</a>       
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade modal-profile" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

> Portfolio Modal pop up JS

```
$('a.portfolio-item').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = $('.modal-body-portfolio');
    var title = $(".modal-title-portfolio");

    content.empty();
    title.empty();
    //var title = $(this).attr("title");
    //$('.modal-title').html(title);
    var img = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/^url\(|\)$/g, "");
    content.html('<img class="img-responsive" src='+ img +'>');
    $(".modal-profile").modal({show:true});
  });
```

> Portfolio Modal pop up HTML

×

```
  </div>
</div>
```

> Service Modal pop up JS

```
$(".row .service-icon").click(function() {
    var content = $(".carousel-inner");
    var title = $(".modal-title-service");

    content.empty();  
    title.empty();

    var id = this.id;  
    var repo = $("#img-repo .item");
    var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
    var active = repoCopy.first();

    active.addClass("active");
    title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
    content.append(repoCopy);

    // show the modal
    $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");
  });
```

> Service Modal pop up HTML

```
    <div class="modal" id="modal-gallery" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title modal-title-service"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modal-body-service">
        <div id="modal-carousel" class="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">           
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Curiousdev it solved my problem. What's the reason behind not needing the both "

Comment: the reason behind dis is when u r getting image value it's already wrapped with `"` at this function `$(this).css('background-image')` so it no longer needed... :-)

Comment: well it's my pleasure :-)

Comment: I am facing another issue now which is related to this modal feature. Could you take a look at my website?

Comment: my website is a single page design. 
There is 2 section in the page which requires popup modal.
It seems like both are interfering with each other.
http://203.174.83.130/~einprodu/test.html

Comment: Hey I have checked this link anchor tag pop up is working fine where's is the second modal pop up ?? It's too late here I'll check by tomorrow morning hope u don't mind

Comment: At the Services and Portfolio section. Sure no rush.

Comment: @juniortan find my updated answer we just need to add distinct class to both modals this is the reason your modal is interfering because of the same class i have updated code here put it and check it'll work

Comment: In short you just need to add  `modal-body-service` class and `modal-title-service` for service section as above and `modal-body-portfolio` class and `modal-title-portfolio` for portfolio section let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: Got it to work by doing just 
**<div class="modal-body portfolio">** and **var content = $('.modal-body.portfolio');**
Thanks for the help!